# Kamailio removing headers from reply

Tags: c, lua, header, sip, kamailio

I am working on a project where I need to send back `302` reply. Everything seems to work, except I can't remove certain headers, i.e. From, Contact, etc. (I don't want to remove them completely, but rather substitute with my own version of it). I use `KEMI` with Lua to do so:

```
KSR.hdr.remove("From")
```

As I mentioned, this does not work (while other functions from `hdr` work fine in the same context, namely `KSR.hdr.append_to_reply(...)`.

I decided to look at the Kamailio source code and found following lines of code in `kemi.c` file:

```
int sr_kemi_hdr_remove(sip_msg_t *msg, str *hname)
{
    ...
        anchor=del_lump(msg, hf->name.s - msg->buf, hf->len, 0);
        if (anchor==0) {
            LM_ERR("cannot remove hdr %.*s\n", hname->len, hname->s);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Looking at the last parameter that `del_lump` takes, it is of type `_hdr_types_t` which describes an `enum` of different header types. Now, in particular to me, there were three headers I was working with:

- From (type 4)
- Contact (type 7)
- Other (type 0)

So my question is, why does that function is hardcoded to take only `OTHER` headers, but not other ones, i.e. `From` and `Contact`? Is that to safeguard from breaking the SIP request (inadvertently removing required headers)?

And as a follow up question, is it even possible to remove `From` and `Contact` from reply messages?

Comment: From is not meant to be removed at all, it is used to inditify the dialog with the from-tag. 
Contact can be removed in theory but it should be replaced by a valid contact header. 
After all a redirect 302 purpose is to give new target uri using the contact field. 

Could you precise what you want to do ? 
Maybe it is possible to modify headers even if removing from and contact is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the 302 is generated by Kamailio, then several headers are copied from the incoming request, like From, To, Call-Id, CSeq. Therefore if you want a different From in the generated reply, change it in the request and then do **msg_apply_changes()**.

Contact headers for redirect (3xx) replies are generated from the destination set of the request (modified R-URI and branches that can be created by **append_branch()**, **lookup("location")** etc.).

More headers can be added to the generated replies using **append_to_reply()**.

Note that I gave the name of the functions for the native kamailio.cfg, but you can find them exported to Kemi as well (by core or textops, textopsx modules).